# Text of textview is overlapping under textview

Tags: ios, swift, textview

My question is simple and I think it is possible but I cant find it.
My design is like this

[image]

I give corner radius to `textview` and also set `textContainerInset` for padding from right and left both side

```
txtview_msg.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 10, 10, 5)
```

Now my problem is like for first 2 line and last 2 line my text goes beneath textview so I need some solution for it.

Please help me into this. Thank you

Comment: @Jacky txtview_msg.clipsToBounds = true try this'

Comment: it's not contain solution of this problem

Comment: @BhavinRamani Its not working. padding hatu e pan gayu

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
UIView *paddingView1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, txtview_msg.frame.size.height - 30)];
txtview_msg.leftView = paddingView1;
txtview_msg.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;

UIView *paddingView2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, txtview_msg.frame.size.height - 30)];
txtview_msg.leftView = paddingView2;
txtview_msg.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create at first a view of same size how much you given, put `cornerRadius` how much you given in `textview` now. than create `textview` `viewSize` - `corner radius`. place the `textview` exactly in middle of view. set the constraints from that view only, than it will work perfect how you want.
check this attached screenshot:

[image: first one is simple text view In second I puted textview inside a view]

Comment: @Jacky check this

Comment: Yeah, I can do this but as per my question my cornerradius is of self.txtview_msg.frame.size.height/2 and its really curvy. So for this solution there is lot of space remaining when curve is at peak both side. Hope U understand